# Disable bcm2708_fb, the HDMI framebuffer device

Tags: framebuffer

I need to *disable* the framebuffer running on `/dev/fb0` via the `bcm2708_fb` kernel module (reason: some tool I use *must* run on `/dev/fb0` and I need my small TFT to be just that - `fb0`).
Disabling `bcm2708_fb` in the kernel leads to a few errors during kernel compilation which I like to forego.

I there a known way to
a) have `bcm2708_fb` in the kernel but
b) *not* load it, thus leaving `/dev/fb0` unpopulated until I load my small TFT framebuffer driver?

[According to the source](https://github.com/macliu010/pi_plus/blob/master/linux/drivers/video/bcm2708_fb.c#L340) of `bcm2708_fb` there's no parameters *not* to load the driver when compiled as a module, according to multiple sources I googled there's no way of *not* loading a compiled-in driver.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing but have a look at https://github.com/notro/fbtft

Comment: That's where I got the FBTFT driver from, of course. Please re-read my request: How do I disable a built-in driver that resides within the kernel itself and is not compiled as a module?

Answer (score 0):

You can set `max_framebuffers=0` in `config.txt` to completely disable framebuffer devices.

To just disable the module, [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/446913/6662) plus looking at the bcm2708_fb code suggests that adding `initcall_blacklist=bcm2708_fb_init` to the kernel command line should do the trick, however I have not tested this.

Alternatively you could write a udev rule to make the default framebuffer appear as `/dev/fb1` and your framebuffer driver appear as `/dev/fb0`, so that you can use both but your own one appears as `/dev/fb0`.

Answer (score -1):

You could use `fbcp` to mirror `/dev/fb0` onto `/dev/fb1`.

See [Github: notro/fbtft -Framebuffer mirroring](https://github.com/notro/fbtft/wiki/Framebuffer-use#framebuffer-mirroring).

Comment: If you could edit your answer to include a synopsis of the details from the link, then that would be great.